# Window Drag Lock In Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, gui, window

I have installed 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10 on my ASUS G53JW Notebook using WUBI. It has an NVIDIA GTX460M Graphics Card. I have installed NVIDIA Driver version 304.54

The problem is that sometimes the whole desktop freezes and some random window gets locked in its position. The locked window has orange circular icons on its borders and a big circle at the center, with arrows inside them. I am unable to drag, click or close the window. Most of the time it happens when I'm typing something really fast in the terminal or browser.

[image: Workspace Screenshot]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you hit a shortcut while typing really fast. You can check shortcuts on nvidia settings or on Ubuntu.
For example [there is "resize window"](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-keyboard-shortcut-list.html) at the bottom.